# How to install Visual Studio for Mac from Terminal (Mac OS)

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, terminal, visual-studio-mac

I would like to install Visual Studio for Mac on ssh.

Therefore, I have to use Terminal for the installation.
I download the .dmg file and copy it from local computer to ssh.

Then, I follow this [link](http://commandlinemac.blogspot.jp/2008/12/installing-dmg-application-from-command.html), but it doesn't work.
I still can't use 'mcs' command to compile C# code.

Can anyone tell me how to install Visual Studio for Mac via Terminal?

Comment: If you are trying to use `mcs`, then you need to install `Mono` ( http://www.mono-project.com) as that contains the compiler(s), .Net frameworks, cmd-line tools, etc... Visual Studio for Mac is "just" an IDE.

Comment: Thank you so much! @SushiHangover I've already install Mono and can use mcs.