# How do I update Visual Studio for Mac / Xamarin Studio from a terminal?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, terminal

I run some mac build agents linked to TFS / DevOps Server. From time to time Visual Studio / Xamarin Studio gets some updates, I want to update Visual Studio via SSH or on via a local Terminal.

On windows I found an UI and Terminal (Command Line) approve:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

I can do something like this on command line for Windows:

> vs_enterprise.exe update --quiet

I found that How-To (which is UI-driven) for a Mac. This steps I do at the moment for every update on each build agent:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/update

I found that here on StackOverflow:
[How to install Visual Studio for Mac from Terminal (Mac OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49727677/how-to-install-visual-studio-for-mac-from-terminal-mac-os)

How can I update Visual Studio for Mac / Xamarin Studio from the Terminal? Is there a similar command-line tool like "vs_enterprise.exe update --quiet" from the windows world for macs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like there is anything built into Visual Studio to let you update from command line.

There is `vstool` in `/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS` which seems to let you update add-ins from command line. But nothing that seems to update Visual Studio itself.

You could perhaps use a third party tool such as homebrew and let that update Visual Studio for you.

Install VS:

```
brew cask install visual-studio
```

Update casks later:

```
brew cask upgrade
```

Not sure if that helps you much though.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I will check it out tomorrow with an empty mac. My first try was failing because visual studio was already installed. On the GitHub page from cask, I found the topic search "https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md#searching-for-casks"

Comment: Hi, THX @Cheesebon, everything works, visual-studio community edition was installed! Do you know if it is possible to change the edition to "pro" or "enterprise"?

Comment: I think the only difference there is whether you are logged into VS or not?